# Replace element in list if it contains a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = ['the dog ran', 'tomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
```

I want to search for the element containing the word Wednesday and replace that element with a line break at the beginning. So:

```
new_list = ['the dog ran', '/ntomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
```

Any help would be great. Everything I've tried has not worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing the items in a list to make a new list calls for a list comprehension. Combine it with the `x if y else z` conditional expression to modify the items as you want.

```
old_list = ['the dog ran', 'tomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
new_list = [('\n' + item) if "Wednesday" in item else item for item in old_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `endswith` in a list comprehension:

```
l = ['the dog ran', 'tomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
new_l = ['/n'+i if i.endswith('Wednesday') else i for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['the dog ran', '/ntomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
```

Comment: `in` is better than `endswith`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension, and conditional expressions:

```
new_list = ['\n{}'.format(i) if 'Wednesday' in i else i for i in list_]
```

**Example:**

```
In [92]: l = ['the dog ran', 'tomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']

In [93]: ['\n{}'.format(i) if 'Wednesday' in i else i for i in l]
Out[93]: ['the dog ran', '\ntomorrow is Wednesday', 'hello sir']
```

As a side note, setting your variable as `list` is a bad idea, as it shadows the builtin `list` type.